# Use Facebook Authentification on different Hosts

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hey I'm writing a java application which should be able to connect the user to their facebook accounts. The application than should be able to post on their Facebook pages.

For now my workflow works quite good. But my java app is hostet by my customers. So I have no specified redirect url available. Because everey customer use a different Domain name.

There is the posibility to redirect to https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html as described here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/.

For now my JSP File looks like:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%
    FBGraph fbConnection = new FBGraph();
%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Java Facebook Login</title>

<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/30c4960fcc.js"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body style="text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-auto">
                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome to Hforms Social Login</h1>
                    <p class="lead">Use this page to login into Facebook to use
                        your Hforms Installtion with your Facebook Pages</p>
                    <hr class="my-4">

                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
                        href="<%=fbConnection.getFBAuthUrl()%>" role="button" onclick="<%= fbConnection.onLinkClick()%>"> <i
                        class="fab fa-facebook"></i> <span>Login into Facebook</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

`getFBAuthUrl()` for now returns `https://www.facebook.com/v6.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=[mySecretID]&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Flogin_success.html&state=wdadwadawdwad&scope=manage_pages,publish_pages,pages_show_list`

When klicking the Link I'm redirected to facbook and have to allow access to my app. When klicking OK there I'm redirected to the facebook success page where the URL is containing the key. But I have no idea how to get the key.

Maybe someone could give me a hint on that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That particular URL is only for handling authentication in a webview, where you have _access_ to the current URL to read the token from it. That’s not the case to begin with with a normal web app.

Comment: I am not sure what the current state of things is regarding App Domains, whether you can add any arbitrary number of different domains there now (didn’t use to be the case; I think it might still depend on the domains belonging to the same business now) - but you would still have to add the Valid OAuth Redirect URIs for each client there then. The other option would be that you handle all of it on under your own domain - send users there first, from your client’s site, trigger login from there and process the result - and then hand the access token back to the client’s system somehow.

Comment: on security reasons I have no access to the users systems. They are running completly standalone.

Comment: You would not need “access” to their systems per se, but they of course would have to be okay with the Facebook user being redirected to your domain first. If that is not an option … well, then what you want is probably not currently possible. Then each of your customers would have to use their _own_ app id, which also means each of them would have to get all the permissions and features your app uses approved in review by Facebook individually.

Comment: Maybe I'm writing a JavaFX or Swing Application to Login the User into Facebook. It seems this is the simplest way. There I can use a web view and have access to the urls.